# Android ConstraintLayout aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a page with ContrainstLayout with an image and a text view. For the Image, I want to have a W:H ratio 1:1. But for some reason, the image always has start and end margin (even I have set the margin to 0)

[image]

Below is the parent page which contains the Layout (in the position of "ViewPager"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCaption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/guideText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

Comment: Please add your layout file

Comment: have you added padding on parent? or does png have any transparent border?

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp. I did try it. it didn't work to me either. Technically I want the image have the full screen width and the height should be the same as width. And I also try to set the width to "math_parent"

Comment: @Aslam. I checked the png. there is no transparent border, and the parent page seems right to me (no start/end margin or padding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio that you specify will give you an *ImageView* that has a ratio of 1:1. Your image maintains its aspect ratio and is positioned within the *ImageView*. I am guessing that the image is a little taller than wide, so that is why you see the bars on the side. To completely fill the 1:1 *ImageView*, you will need to somehow crop the image on the top and/or bottom

Try the following for the *ImageView*. I think that you will find that it fills the width of the screen and crops the height of the image. See [scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) for details on how `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` works. [Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) also comes in handy.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mypngimage"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for me. Thanks for saving my day